# Triple venn-diagram in R: How to get proportions of the area right

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to compare different test methods using venn diagrams in R by using the package VennDiagram. I run into the problem that areas are not proportional to the size of the numbers.
It all works nicely then I compare 2 test-methods as follows:

```
draw.pairwise.venn(44, 32, 28, c("TestA", "TestB"), fill = c("red", "blue"))
```

But, when I try to compare 3 methods, the areas are not proportional anymore. I have tried to add some "extras" like eulerr.d = TRUE and scaled = TRUE, but don't seem to help.

```
draw.triple.venn(44, 39, 32, 39, 25, 28, 25, c("TestA", "TestC", "TestB"),  fill = c("red", "green", "blue"), euler.d = TRUE, scaled = TRUE)
```

Any tips on how to get around this?

Thank you in advance,

Bjorn

Comment: possible alt: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/vignettes/venn-diagrams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Venn nor Euler diagrams require overlap areas to be proportional to magnitude of content, tho' I understand it makes the graph marginally more useful.   I strongly recommend investigating the package [`UpSetR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/index.html) which provides some really cool, and instructive graphic representations of set overlaps.

In the meantime, I would go with user20650's suggestion to play with [`eulerr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/) and see if you find it easier to get the overlay plot you want.
Also at CRAN:   bvenn, venneuler, vennplot, and several other packages of possible interest.

Side nit:   If you are only plotting overlaps with content, then it's an Euler, not Venn diagram.

Comment: UpSetR is great. I can see good ways to use that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you've used do create a scaled plot for *some* sets of values, e.g.

```
draw.triple.venn(1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, c("TestA", "TestC", "TestB"),  
                 fill = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

[image]

It seems that for other sets of parameters it is not possible (or not coded) to make the areas proportional to the values

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display arbitrary proportional Venn or Euler diagrams for three or more sets using circles. There is a closed thread in stackoverflow about different packages to do this. A couple of options would be `eulerr` ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/vignettes/introduction.html)), which uses ellipses and a loss function, and the one I developed, `nVennR` ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html)), which uses other shapes and keeps almost exact proportions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Will check this.